# How do I fix this command prompt error regarding these error messages?

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, dart, command

So I already have these installed. I had Android Studio 4.2.0 but deleted it and got 4.1.0 to fit the circumstances. Now, it's telling me to get 4.0 and 4.1, which is confusing me a lot. I have Flutter and Dart installed, so I don't understand where I went wrong.[image: The proof of installation]  s[image: The Command Prompt error]

Answer (score 0):

I think your previous version of Android Studio isn't deleted properly. Try deleting its caches too. And I don't think these dart and flutter plugins installation is required for you as you are using visual studio code.

Try running a sample project and see if it runs or not.
**Happy Coding**

Comment: How do I do the bundled Java part?

Comment: If you are into making changes in the java code then you can use android studio without that plugin too! Or are you saying any other thing?